# Issue with generating Client Assertion key using Laravel for Singpass

Tags: php, laravel, jwt, pem

I'm trying to generate client_assertion key for client login authentication for [Singpass](https://www.singpass.gov.sg/main) portal but they give error saying that the JWT token which i'm using for client assertion have invalid or missing claims but I'm using all the claim specified in their [Docs](https://stg-id.singpass.gov.sg/docs/authorization/api#_assertion_jwt_structure)

I've used [Tymon JWTAuth](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth) to create the assertion

```
$jwt = new Lcobucci(new Builder(), new Parser(), '', 'ES256', [
    'private' => 'file://' . base_path('keys/private.pem'),
    'public' => 'file://' . base_path('keys/public.pem')
]);

return $jwt->encode([
    'sub' => "******LESBX********ifeGBAU******",
    'aud' => "https://stg-ig.singpass.gov.sg",
    'iss' => "******LESBX********ifeGBAU******",
    'iat' => now()->timestamp,
    'exp' => now()->addMinute()->timestamp,
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the audience right? Shouldn't it be `https://stg-id.singpass.gov.sg` (`id` instead of `ig`)?